# Webaudio :: Play Recorded Audio

Tags: web-audio-api

I want to play the recorded audio using microphone.

After recording it as 32 bit arrays

```
    let left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    let tempLeftChannel = this.state.leftChannel;
    tempLeftChannel.push(new Float32Array(left));
    this.setState({ leftChannel: tempLeftChannel });
```

Now In the leftChannel array, I had chunk of audio data. Now, I want to play them in the browser. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You leave quite a bit out from your snippet, but perhaps the following will give you an idea of one way to play out the float array that you have.  Let `context` be the `AudioContext` that you probably have.

```
let buffer = new AudioBuffer({length: leftChannel.length,
                              sampleRate: context.sampleRate});
buffer.copyToChannel(leftChannel, 0);

let source = new AudioBufferSourceNode(context, {buffer: buffer});

source.connect(context.destination);
source.start();
```